# I will include google maps funciton in my Android Apps, how to show current location

Tags: android

I will include google maps funciton in my Android Apps, how to show current location??
When I search google maps in google, it includes many google maps API, which one should I use? Is there any example?
Also, is there any limit using the API? If yes, any solution to solve?

Comment: Given that you are tagging this with Android, I would guess you would want to use the Android Google Maps API. There are examples all over the place. Do you have a specific problem you need help with?

Comment: I want to include the navigation function in my apps. But I don't know how to start?

Answer (score 1):

[Follow this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/mapview-to-center-on-current-location.html)

> I want to include the navigation function in my apps.

If you're thinking driving  turn by turn Navigation, sorry it is not officially supported